# Getting a "...must implement abstract method NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback error

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I'm trying to learn NFC, using the document at http://www.tappednfc.com/wp-content/uploads/TAPPED-NFCDeveloperGuide-Part1.pdf.

Where my class id defined, i get the following error:
must implement abstract method `NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback.onNdefPushComplete`

I have the following method defined

```
public void OnNdefPushComplete( NfcEvent arg0)
{
    mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
}
```

Wouldn't this be the callback the error message is saying I need?

The complete code looks as follows

```
public class BeamActivity extends Activity
                          implements CreateNdefMessageCallback,
                                     OnNdefPushCompleteCallback {
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // see if there is a NFC interface
        mNfcAdapter=NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter==null) Toast.makeText(this,"no adapter",
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this,this);
        mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this,this);
    }

    public void OnNdefPushComplete( NfcEvent arg0) {
        mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Mesg Sent",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            } // end switch
        } // end handle mesg
    }; // end new

    // create call back code
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        String text="hello world";
        //NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        //        NfcUtils.
        //    }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onRestart();

        if (mNfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            processIntent( getIntent() );
        }
    }

    void processIntent( Intent intet) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs= intet.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                mNfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES );

        NdefMessage msg = (  NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        String s= new String(  msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Java is case-sensitive. The method `OnNdefPushCompleteCallback.onNdefPushComplete(...)` starts with a lower-case "o" (see the interface definition of `OnNdefPushCompleteCallback`:

```
public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent arg0) {
    mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was going nuts trying to figure out the issue